# Flood safe/auto-shutoff hose triggering for no reason

Tags: plumbing

The hot water line to our kitchen sink has one of those [flood safe/auto-shutoff hoses](http://www.watts.com/pages/whatsnew/floodsafe_connectors.asp). It has started triggering and cutting off the water whenever we turn the hot water on more than half way. I took it off and cleaned a little debris out of one end of the hose but after reconnecting the problem continues. What could be causing it to trigger? Should I just replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the amazon reviews on [Floodsafe](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_7?url=search-alias=tools&field-keywords=floodsafe&x=0&y=0&sprefix=floodsa) hoses, most of them say the same thing, great idea, but they shutoff too easily. That, and they won't stop a small leak, only a catastrophic rupture. So your best bet is to replace them with a non-floodsafe high quality hose.

If you're going to be away for an extended time, have someone check on your place from time to time, and it doesn't hurt to shutoff the water.

Comment: Sounds good, those hoses seem like a pain.